# How can I make event.stopPropagation() work for an input field inside a form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events, keyboard-events

I have a form with a few input fields. One of the fields is used to set tags. Whenever the user hits enter, then I want the tag to be added.

All that works just fine. My problem is that when the user hits enter, the event propagates to the form and the form thinks it's being submitted. I don't want that to happen. I want the form to only be submitted when the designated submit button is clicked.

This is my form:

```
      <form>

        <div className="tiny-margin-bottom medium-margin-top">
          <div className="tags__container">
            <InputField
              type="text"
              placeHolder="Add tags that are related to your business (for example 'Restaurant')"
              value={tagInput}
              onChange={setTagInput}
              onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
              label="Hit 'Enter' to save tags"
            />
            <div className="tags__submit" onClick={addTag}>
              &rarr;
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="tags">
            {values && values.tags ? renderTags(values.tags) : null}
          </div>
        </div>


        <div className="popup__button medium-margin-top">
          <button className="boxed-button " onClick={handleSubmit}>
            Create Project
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

And these are my two functions:

For when the enter is hit in the input field:

```
  const handleKeyPress = event => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      addTag();
      return false;
    }
  };
```

For form submittion:

```
  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    switch (true) {
      case !values.title:
        setFormError("Please give your project a title");
        break;

      case !values.country:
        setFormError("Please choose the country of your target audience");
        break;

      case !values.lang:
        setFormError("Please choose the language of your target audience");
        break;

      case values && values.tags && values.tags.length >= 3:
        setFormError("Please add at least 3 tags");
        break;

      default:
        setSubmitting(true);
        newProject(values, setSubmitting);
        setFormError(null);
        break;
    }
  };
```

Comment: The [`keypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event) event is deprecated. Use [`beforeinput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeinput) or [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event) instead.

Comment: Ok thanks, I've changed it, but it still doesn't fix my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the label:
Add `<form onSubmit={addLabelFunction} ... >`. So now hitting enter will invoke this function directly. 
Also add

```
<button 
  type="button" 
  ...
/>
```

This will ensure that onSubmit does not trigger your `handleSubmit` function.

Ideally you can then remove `event.stopPropogation()`. It is generally a good idea to let the event propogate unless user intentionally wants to prevent it for some use case.